# Trying to swap tokens in UniswapV3 with SwapRoute unsuccessfully calling exactInputSingle

Tags: ethers.js, uniswapv3

Tring to perform a swap in a dapp of mine on uniswap router v3.

```
export const swapFromRouter = async (
  tokenIn: string,
  tokenOut: string,
  fee: string,
  recipient: string,
  deadline: string,
  amountIn: string,
  amountOutMin: string,
  sqrtPriceLimitX96: string
) => {
  try{
    const params = {
      tokenIn: tokenIn,
      tokenOut: tokenOut,
      fee: fee,
      recipient: recipient,
      deadline: deadline,
      amountIn: amountIn,
      amountOutMin: amountOutMin,
      sqrtPriceLimitX96: sqrtPriceLimitX96
    }

    const signer = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum).getSigner()
    const router = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, SwapRouter.abi, signer)
    router.exactInputSingle(params, {value: '0'})
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error, 'this is the error for swapFromRoute')
  }
}
```

getting this error

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.0)
```

I'm passing a value there so i really do not know what i'm doing wrong. Can i have some third option?

Answer (score 1):

Ethers prefers many things as a big number format

you would need to import the BigNumber from ethers, and convert any line/variable with that error to a BN

```
import { ethers, BigNumber } from "ethers";
BigNumber.from("0")
```